# PyInstaller - Error Permission Denied, read-only issue

Tags: python, windows-7, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a PyQt application with PyInstaller like this with admin privileges

```
python PyInstaller -noconsole <projectfolder>
```

It worked quiet well a couple of days ago, but now I get this Error (at the bottom of the Traceback):

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Uploader'
```

(Uploader is my source folder)

Also I noticed that in the project folder's properties (Windows 7 by the way) read-only seems to be half enabled (there is a blue square in the box).

So I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I don't know if the read-only thing has anything to do with it or whether this is just normal.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?